# Using Parse Javascript SDK in Objective J Cappuccino Project

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cappuccino, objective-j

Since valid Javascript code can be executed in Objective J, how would I go about adding the Parse SDK?

Following this tutorial: [Parse JS SDK](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/web/existing)

In my project, I can't add the HTML script tag:

```
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.14.min.js"></script>
```

nor can I use:

```
var Parse = require('parse');
```

What is the correct way to import Parse?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the script tag to your index.html and index-debug.html. Inside of these files you will see:

```
<!-- Custom javascript goes here -->
<!-- End custom javascript -->
```

So change this to:

```
<!-- Custom javascript goes here -->
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.14.min.js"></script>
<!-- End custom javascript -->
```

Then according to the document you referred to you need to connect your app to Parse server:

```
Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse'
```

What I would do to add this to the 'init' method:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID");
        Parse.serverURL = 'http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse'
    }

   return self;
}
```

Start Python web server:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Check your app in the browser at localhost:8000